# How to install NLTK modules in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, nltk

Hey i'd like to install the NLTK pos_tag on my Heroku server. How can i do so. Please give me the steps as im new to the Heroku server system.

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26334947/181337

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385303/how-to-install-nltk-modules-in-heroku/35895877

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk

Answer (score 19):

I just added official `nltk` support to the buildpack!

Simply add a `nltk.txt` file with a list of corpora you want installed, and everything should work as expected.

Comment: What is corpora ??

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

[As Kenneth Reitz pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257701/387337), a much simpler solution has been added to the heroku-python-buildpack.  Add a `nltk.txt` file to your root directory and list your corpora inside.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk for details.

---

#### Original Answer

Here's a solution that allows you to install the NLTK data directly on Heroku without adding it to your git repo.

I used similar steps to install [Textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) on Heroku, which uses NLTK as a dependency. I've made some minor adjustments to my original code in steps 3 and 4 that should work for an NLTK only installation.

The default heroku buildpack includes a [`post_compile` step](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile) that runs after all of the default build steps have been completed:

```
# post_compile
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f bin/post_compile ]; then
    echo "-----> Running post-compile hook"
    chmod +x bin/post_compile
    sub-env bin/post_compile
fi
```

As you can see, it looks in your project directory for your own `post_compile` file in the `bin` directory, and it runs it if it exists.  You can use this hook to install the nltk data.

1. Create the `bin` directory in the root of your local project.
2. Add your own `post_compile` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/post_compile
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   if [ -f bin/install_nltk_data ]; then
       echo "-----> Running install_nltk_data"
       chmod +x bin/install_nltk_data
       bin/install_nltk_data
   fi

   echo "-----> Post-compile done"
   ```
3. Add your own `install_nltk_data` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/install_nltk_data
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   source $BIN_DIR/utils

   echo "-----> Starting nltk data installation"

   # Assumes NLTK_DATA environment variable is already set
   # $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'

   # Install the nltk data
   # NOTE: The following command installs the averaged_perceptron_tagger corpora, 
   # so you may want to change for your specific needs.  
   # See http://www.nltk.org/data.html
   python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger

   # If using Textblob, use this instead:
   # python -m textblob.download_corpora lite

   # Open the NLTK_DATA directory
   cd ${NLTK_DATA}

   # Delete all of the zip files
   find . -name "*.zip" -type f -delete

   echo "-----> Finished nltk data installation"
   ```
4. Add `nltk` to your `requirements.txt` file (Or `textblob` if you are using Textblob).
5. Commit all of these changes to your repo.
6. Set the NLTK_DATA environment variable on your heroku app.

   ```
   $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'
   ```
7. Deploy to Heroku.  You will see the `post_compile` step trigger at the end of the deployment, followed by the nltk download.

I hope you found this helpful!  Enjoy!

Comment: I'm getting this error after following your instructions. -  import bp_cli
ImportError: No module named bp_cli
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: Hi @Sainath.  I'm not familiar with your error, but it doesn't seem to be related to NLTK.  You might be missing some requirements in your requirements.txt file for other parts of your application.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. @Sainath did you ever figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Figured it out. I didn't follow the last instruction: heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'. Did that and it worked great!

Comment: Important note:  heroku python build pack v97 changed behavior, causing the nltk_data directory to be omitted.  See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/356 for fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use simple functionalities like pos_tag, tokenizer, stemming, etc. then you can do the following steps

1. mention nltk in requirements.txt
2. mention following modules in nltk.txt

   - wordnet
   - pros_cons
   - reuters
   - hmm_treebank_pos_tagger
   - maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
   - universal_tagset
   - punkt
   - averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru
   - averaged_perceptron_tagger
   - snowball_data
   - rslp
   - porter_test
   - vader_lexicon
   - treebank
   - dependency_treebank

Comment: what about for stopwords, just "stopwords"?

Comment: you can add stopwords to nltk.txt file.

Comment: How did you come up with this list? I only need `nltk.data`, `nltk.word_tokenize`, `nltk.post_tag`, `nltk.sentiment`. Do you know what I should include in the `nltk.txt` file in this case?

Comment: Answering myself... If anyone needs to know the required packages to mention in `nltk.txt`, check the heroku log (go to the app in the website > More > View Logs), and see the details. E.g. if you're missing `punkt` it would say: `nltk.download('punkt')`, so you add `punkt` in `nltk.txt` etc. I ended up needing only `punkt`, `vader_lexicon`, `averaged_perceptron_tagger`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps.

1. nltk.txt needs to present at the root folder
2. Add the modules you want to download like punkt, stopwords as separate row items
3. Change the line ending from windows to UNIX

Changing the line ending is a very important step. Can be easily done through Sublime Text or Notepad++. In Sublime Text, it can done from the View menu, then Line Endings.

Hope this helps