# LookupError: Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, flask, nltk

I am trying to run a webapp on Heroku using Flask. The webapp is programmed in Python with the NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit library).

One of the file has the following header:

```
import nltk, json, operator
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
```

When the webpage with the stopwords code is called, it produces the following error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK  
  Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()  
  Searched in:  
    - '/app/nltk_data'  
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'  
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'  
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'  
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'  
**********************************************************************
```

The exact code used:

```
#remove punctuation  
toker = RegexpTokenizer(r'((?<=[^\w\s])\w(?=[^\w\s])|(\W))+', gaps=True) 
data = toker.tokenize(data)  

#remove stop words and digits 
stopword = stopwords.words('english')  
data = [w for w in data if w not in stopword and not w.isdigit()]
```

The webapp on Heroku doesn't produce the Lookup error when `stopword = stopwords.words('english')` is commented out.

The code runs without a glitch on my local computer. I have have installed the required libraries on my computer using

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

The virtual environment provided by Heroku was running when I tested the code on my computer.

I have also tried the NLTK provided by two different sources, but the `LookupError` is still there. The two sources I used are:
http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nltk/nltk-2.0.1rc4.zip
https://github.com/nltk/nltk.git

Comment: try with this https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/444#issuecomment-850093747

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the corpus ('stopwords' in this case) doesn't get uploaded to Heroku. Your code works on your local machine because it already has the NLTK corpus. Please follow these steps to solve the issue.

1. Create a new directory in your project (let's call it 'nltk_data')
2. Download the NLTK corpus in that directory. You will have to configure that during the download.
3. Tell nltk to look for this particular path. Just add `nltk.data.path.append('path_to_nltk_data')` to the Python file that's actually using nltk.
4. Now push the app to Heroku.

Hope that solves the problem. Worked for me!

Comment: If you want to install NLTK data on Heroku without adding it to your git repo, see my solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37574162/387337

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

[As Kenneth Reitz pointed out](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile), a much simpler solution has been added to the heroku-python-buildpack.  Add a `nltk.txt` file to your root directory and list your corpora inside.  See [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) for details.

---

#### Original Answer

Here's a cleaner solution that allows you to install the NLTK data directly on Heroku without adding it to your git repo.

I used similar steps to install [Textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) on Heroku, which uses NLTK as a dependency. I've made some minor adjustments to my original code in steps 3 and 4 that should work for an NLTK only installation.

The default heroku buildpack includes a [`post_compile` step](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/hooks/post_compile) that runs after all of the default build steps have been completed:

```
# post_compile
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f bin/post_compile ]; then
    echo "-----> Running post-compile hook"
    chmod +x bin/post_compile
    sub-env bin/post_compile
fi
```

As you can see, it looks in your project directory for your own `post_compile` file in the `bin` directory, and it runs it if it exists.  You can use this hook to install the nltk data.

1. Create the `bin` directory in the root of your local project.
2. Add your own `post_compile` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/post_compile
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   if [ -f bin/install_nltk_data ]; then
       echo "-----> Running install_nltk_data"
       chmod +x bin/install_nltk_data
       bin/install_nltk_data
   fi

   echo "-----> Post-compile done"
   ```
3. Add your own `install_nltk_data` file to the `bin` directory.

   ```
   # bin/install_nltk_data
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   source $BIN_DIR/utils

   echo "-----> Starting nltk data installation"

   # Assumes NLTK_DATA environment variable is already set
   # $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'

   # Install the nltk data
   # NOTE: The following command installs the stopwords corpora, 
   # so you may want to change for your specific needs.  
   # See http://www.nltk.org/data.html
   python -m nltk.downloader stopwords

   # If using Textblob, use this instead:
   # python -m textblob.download_corpora lite

   # Open the NLTK_DATA directory
   cd ${NLTK_DATA}

   # Delete all of the zip files
   find . -name "*.zip" -type f -delete

   echo "-----> Finished nltk data installation"
   ```
4. Add `nltk` to your `requirements.txt` file (Or `textblob` if you are using Textblob).
5. Commit all of these changes to your repo.
6. Set the NLTK_DATA environment variable on your heroku app.

   ```
   $ heroku config:set NLTK_DATA='/app/nltk_data'
   ```
7. Deploy to Heroku.  You will see the `post_compile` step trigger at the end of the deployment, followed by the nltk download.

I hope you found this helpful!  Enjoy!

Comment: Important note:  heroku python build pack v97 changed behavior, causing the nltk_data directory to be omitted.  See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/356 for fix.